# WshShell.SendKeys sends keys incorrectly

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys, notepad, wsh

Ok, so I am trying to write a program that brings notepad to the foreground, then prints text to it with the SendKeys method. The problem is

```
`set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Wscript.sleep 10000
WshShell.AppActivate "Untitled - Notepad"
Wscript.sleep 1000
WshShell.Sendkeys "Essay Finisher 2.5.5"
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "Checking for updates"
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "."
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{BACKSPACE}"
Wscript.sleep 100
WshShell.Sendkeys "No updates found"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
Wscript.sleep 1000
WshShell.Sendkeys "Beginning text recognition engine..."
Wscript.sleep 3000
WshShell.Sendkeys "Text recognition engine started successfully"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "Please type the beginning sentence of your essay: you have 30 seconds"
Wscript.sleep 30000
WshShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "Sentence recognition complete, please wait"
Wscript.sleep 200`
```

results in this:Essay FinisheRE s2s.a5y. 5Finisher 2.5.5
Checking f
or UCPhdeactkeisng for updatesNo updates found
No updates found
Beginning text reCBOeggniintniionng  etnegxitn er.e.c.ognition engine...Text recognitiOTNe xetn grineec osgtnairttieodn  seuncgcienses fsutlalryt
eDP lseuacscee stsyfpuel lty
hEP lbeeagsien ntiynpge  stehnet ebnecgei nonfi nygo usre netsesnacye :O fy oyuo uhra vees s3a0y :Se cyoonud shave 30 seconds
When it should result in:
Essay Finisher 2.5.5
Checking for updates...(a nice animation here)No updates found
Beginning text recognition engine... Text recognition engine started
Anyways, you get the point.
How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't do this. All it takes is for someone to click elsewhere and a flurry of keystrokes will be sent to the new active window.  If you want to display status updates, use a command-line script (`cscript`) and use `WScript.Echo` or `StdOut.Write/WriteLine`.

Comment: I need to print to notepad later in the program anyways, so how would I do that without it freaking out?

Comment: You could create and write to a textfile (see `FileSystemObject`, `CreateTextFile`, etc) and then display it onscreen when you're done (see `WshShell.Run`), if that's what's needed.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I ran just ran it and it produced the correct results. Thanks anyway!